# .mov file is not playing video in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, quicktime

I've recorded 7 videos yesterday. All recorded on a Canon 5D Mark III. The files are playing fine from Finder and Quicktime. But when I import them to After Effects, **only one of them** is not playing any video but just sound. After Effects imports the file as audio file, as it looks to me, still, it says, it is a file of the type "Quicktime".

Does anyone have an idea, what I could look into or what I could try?

Finder's file info says:

- Dimensions: 1920x1080
- Codecs: H.264, Linear PCM, Timecode Color
- Profile: HD (1-1-1)
- Duration: 11:49

Adobe Premiere CC 2018 does also play the video as it should. I'm quite a bit confused and have no idea, where to look or what to try.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the codec informations from your video file using [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/fr/MediaInfo) or FFMPEG ?

As Premiere Pro plays well the video, you can export it to a lossless format such as Apple ProRes and then re-open it in After Effect.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. You could try installing K Lite Codec Pack. Reboot

I’d also clear your Media Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it's not working.  But for a quick fix, I'd transcode the video in Premiere to 1920x1080 ProRes 422 and see if that works in After Effects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend installing the official **Microsoft Camera Codec Pack** if you haven't already.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829

See if that solves it.

Comment: Why a 2nd answer? Also, note that OP is on a Mac.